# Is this slide/shift slide?

Tags: guitar, tablature

I found this in a riff, but I don't know the meaning of `(sl)`. I suspect it means slide, however, the slide symbol is `/` or `\`.

> g--(sl)----(sl)----7----

Could someone clarify this, please? And why there are two?

The complete riff. The song is *Walk Of Life*.

> e-------8---------------
>
> b--8-10---10-8-6--------
>
> g--(sl)----(sl)----7----
>
> d-----------------------
>
> a-----------------------
>
> e-----------------------

Comment: Can you also provide the song?

Comment: @shev Sure, _Walk Of Life_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means slide. There are many variations in how tab is written. Some people will use sl, and some use /. Bends are sometimes notated with an arrow and a number (usually 1/2 or 1) to indicates how may tones to bend up, sometimes it will be like --7-b-(9)- meaning bend the note at the 7th fret until it matches the pitch of the note at the 9th fret. If in doubt use your ears to tell you if it sounds correct.

As to why there are 2, it could mean pick the string again during the slide. Again, try to use your ears to judge. Many tabs are not totally accurate and you should err on the side of what your ears tell you sounds right.